# How to determine if a grid cell is within an enclosed perimeter of cells

Tags: java, javafx, tile, discrete-mathematics, game-development

I've been working on a game (in JavaFX) where a player draws a path on a playing board and when he closes the path the interior tiles become his controlled area.

I've seen [an approach to this for polygons](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/) that almost works. I iterate through the tiles to the right of the point in question and count how many times I enter a series of tiles that are part of the perimeter. if it's odd, it's inside (with a count of 1 being a special case).

The problem is points P1 vs P2 in the drawing below. Counting to the right both will have identical counts but one is inside, one is outside the enclosed area. I can't figure out how to define this special case.

Any pointers or thoughts are more than welcome.

[image]

Edited in response to the first comment: This example shows how looking above/below and/or left/right for points on both sides to make a determination may not work.

[image]

Comment: why are you not checking points vertically, i.e. check if tiles present both above and below. with this approach you need not worry about number of tiles above or below.

Comment: I edited my question to add an example where looking up/down and/or left/right won't quite work, either. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not consider points *sitting* on a border cell. You have to define if such a point is considered to be inside or outside of the area.

**Algorithm:**

1. Determine the smallest rectangle `R` enclosing the area but sharing no cells with the area.
2. Mark the point `P`, for which to determine if it is inside or outside the area, as `unvisited`.
3. If there are no cells marked as `unvisited`, `P` is inside the area.
4. Pick an arbitrary cell `C` marked as `unvisited` and mark it as `visited`.
5. If the cell `C` is a border cell of `R`, `P` is outside the area.
6. Pick all nighbor cells of `C` (top, bottom, left, right) which are not marked as `unvisited` or `visited` or are a border cell of the area, and mark them as `unvisited`.
7. Continue with 3.

**Example 1:**

[image: Point outside area]

In this example the point `P` is outside the area. This gets detected by step `5.` of the algorithm for the cell rendered in green.

**Example 2:**

[image: Point inside area]

In this example the point `P` is inside the area. This gets detected by step `3.` of the algorithm if you would continue with the remaining two unvisited cells.

**Example 3:**

[image: Point outside area]

In this example the point `P` is outside the area. This gets detected by step `5.` of the algorithm for the cells rendered in green.

Comment: That looks like a nice approach, thanks for taking the time to respond. It's simple and should be more than efficient enough for my needs. Thanks, off to code and test!